# Regarding null & undefined with logical js operators

Tags: javascript, boolean, logic

Is there a difference in checking like so:

```
if (article.geolocation === null || article.geolocation === undefined){...}
```

vs.

```
if (!article.geolocation){...}
```

I know its a simple question. I am just unsure.

Edit: These two ifs produce different results for me.

Comment: Yes because there are a bunch of truthy and falsely values....

Comment: did you mean `if(!article.geolocation)`? Without the `!`, those statements are completely dissimilar. With the `!` they're still different, but at least they have some similarity

Comment: `0, "", null, undefined, false` all evaluate the same in the `if () {}` expression.

Comment: ok. i edited this. thanks. thats what i meant @NicholasTower

Comment: thank you @CatalinIancu thats what i was wondering. it is working now btw.